# spray.json.DeserializationException: Expected List as JsArray?

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

I am using `spray-json` and this is what I am doing

```
import java.io.File

import spray.json._

import scala.io.Source

case class WorkConfig(configName: String,
                      logSource: String,
                      logType: String,
                      afterProcessingFileAction: String,
                      recursiveFind: Boolean = false,
                      processZipFiles: Boolean = false) {
}

object WorkConfigParser {

  object WorkOrderItemJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val workOrderItemFormat = jsonFormat6(WorkConfig.apply)
  }


  def get(workOrderJson: File): List[WorkConfig] = {
    import WorkOrderItemJsonProtocol._
    val json: JsValue = Source.fromFile(workOrderJson).mkString.toJson
    json.convertTo[List[WorkConfig]]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val items: List[WorkConfig] = WorkConfigParser.get(new File("resources/workConfigSample.json"))
    items.foreach((x: WorkConfig) => println(x.afterProcessingFileAction))
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I see

```
Exception in thread "main" spray.json.DeserializationException: Expected List as JsArray, but got "[\n  {\n    \"configName\": \"bluecoat\",\n    \"logSource\": \"/root/fw1/logs/bc\",\n    \"logType\": \"bluecoat\",\n    \"recursiveFind\": true,\n    \"processZipFiles\": false,\n    \"afterProcessingFileAction\": \"delete\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"configName\": \"mcAfee\",\n    \"logSource\": \"/root/fw1/logs/mcafee\",\n    \"logType\": \"mcafee\",\n    \"recursiveFind\": true,\n    \"processZipFiles\": true,\n    \"afterProcessingFileAction\": \"delete\"\n  }\n]\n\n\n"
    at spray.json.package$.deserializationError(package.scala:23)
    at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1.read(CollectionFormats.scala:29)
    at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1.read(CollectionFormats.scala:25)
    at spray.json.JsValue.convertTo(JsValue.scala:31)
    at com.logprocessor.inputs.WorkConfigParser$.get(WorkConfig.scala:27)
    at com.logprocessor.inputs.WorkConfigParser$.main(WorkConfig.scala:31)
    at com.logprocessor.inputs.WorkConfigParser.main(WorkConfig.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

What is wrong going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You are using toJson instead of using parseJson.** - Converting json String to JsValue should be doing using parseJson.

```
@ val w = WorkConfig("a","b","c","d")

w: WorkConfig = WorkConfig("a", "b", "c", "d", false, false)

@ val l = List(w,w)

l: List[WorkConfig] = List(WorkConfig("a", "b", "c", "d", false, false),
WorkConfig("a", "b", "c", "d", false, false))

@ l.toJson.toString
res48: String = """
[{"configName":"a","logType":"c","recursiveFind":false,
"processZipFiles":false,"afterProcessingFileAction":"d","logSource":"b
{"configName":"a","logType":"c","recursiveFind":false,
"processZipFiles":false,"afterProcessingFileAction":"d","logSource":"b"}]
"""

@ res48.parseJson
res49: JsValue =  [{"configName":"a","logType":"c","recursiveFind":false,
"processZipFiles":false,"afterProcessingFileAction":"d","logSource":"b
{"configName":"a","logType":"c","recursiveFind":false,
"processZipFiles":false,"afterProcessingFileAction":"d","logSource":"b"}]

@ res49.convertTo[List[WorkConfig]]
res50: List[WorkConfig] = List(WorkConfig("a", "b", "c", "d", false,
false), WorkConfig("a", "b", "c", "d", false, false))
```